# Responsive image slider prblem

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I am working on a website, with a responsive slider. However, while the image in the slider divs get smaller when i scale the browser window down, it does not keep the right dimensions when i scale it back. (the image gets wide, but no higher). I have tried a lot, and cant seem to figure it out.

This is an example of the site: [URL-REMOVED]

Hope some of you clever guys can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style.css delete or comment out :

```
img{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

That does the trick for me.